# Convert String to Currency

Tags: c#, string

Im trying to detect if my string has a lenght > 4 convert it to my local currency otherwise make it display no decimal's something like this:

This is my code:

```
var listDay = data.Where(c => c.Fecha >= actualDate && c.Fecha <= actualDateMax).ToList();
var haveDataDay = listDay.Count() > 0;

<h4 class="semi-bold">
    @if (haveDataDay)
    { @valueDateDay.ToString("F2") }
    else
    { @this.FP("lbl.loader.nodata") }
</h4>
```

But i dont know how to check this

Someone has any idea?

Comment: "if my string" - what string you are talking about? Why would one ever call `.ToString(...)` on a string (unless they need NRE)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov my guess is that `valueDateDay` is a decimal or float since `ToString()` on a string doesn't take params

Comment: @Eonasdan this question is no longer eligible for automatic deletion - you may as well edit it in shape...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this but this works just fine:

```
var valueDateDay = 1000;
Console.WriteLine(valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay.ToString().Length > 4 ? "N0" : "C2"));
valueDateDay = 100000;
Console.WriteLine(valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay.ToString().Length > 4 ? "N0" : "C2"));
```

[See it in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kh4V4I)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what your variables mean but try:

```
string currency;
currency = valueDateDay.ToString().Lenght > 4 ? "NO" : "C2";
```